# Error PublicKeyCredential.isConditionalMediationSupported() is not a function

Tags: webauthn

I'm on https://passkeys.dev/docs/use-cases/bootstrapping/#authenticating-the-user and walking through the 'bootstraping` section and I get an error while trying to follow along:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrDig.png)

I'm using Brave 1.45.133 Chromium: 107.0.5304.141

I tried running

```
const isCMSupported =
        PublicKeyCredential.isConditionalMediationSupported();
      console.log({ isCMSupported });
```

and I expected true or false but instead got an error

Uncaught TypeError: PublicKeyCredential.isConditionalMediationSupported is not a function

Comment: For anyone on Windows 10 and wanting to debug conditional UI, turn on virtual authenticator environment to get conditional UI https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/webauthn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `isConditionalMediationAvailable()` method is a "recent" addition, it may not be available in all browsers. Until there is more widespread adoption, you will need to expand on the logic to check:

1. Is the method available
2. If available, what is the return value

If the method is not available, then you can assume that conditional mediation isn't either.

You can use the code below - it's not as elegant as the single one liner offered by `isConditionalMediationAvailable()`, but is necessary until there is widespread adoption.

```
const mediationAvailable = () => {
  const pubKeyCred = PublicKeyCredential;
  // Check if the function exists on the browser - Not safe to assume as the page will crash if the function is not available
  //typeof check is used as browsers that do not support mediation will not have the 'isConditionalMediationAvailable' method available
  if (
    typeof pubKeyCred.isConditionalMediationAvailable === "function" &&
    pubKeyCred.isConditionalMediationAvailable()
  ) {
    console.log("Conditional Mediation is available");
    return true;
  }
  console.log("Conditional Mediation is not available");
  return false;
};
```

Comment: This explanation is correct, however `PublicKeyCredential.isConditionalMediationAvailable()` (when available) returns a promise (note the passkeys.dev example `await`s it.
Assuming `isConditionalMediationAvailable` will always be either undefined or a function (I find this a reasonable assumption) then you can use this one liner : `const isCMSupported = await PublicKeyCredential.isConditionalMediationAvailable?.() ?? false;`